# Is it right to go the cold turkey way when babies cry?

Tags: crying, twins

My babies troubling me and each other . They are 11 mo twins .
I have decided to put them in their separate cot into their rooms when they cry and come back to their room once they stop crying. Does this sound cruel ?

Comment: Sounds very cruel. They are babies after all, and babies have needs you.

Comment: I am a stay at.home mum. Babies are always slapping each other and hurting. Also they cry a lot. I am very sleep deprived. Also my step daughter is giving us a lot of trouble .

Comment: It'll get better in a year.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of people try to ferberize their children and some studies have shown it has benefits. For the most part though when babies cry it's because there is a physiological need for them to cry, hunger, diaper or they need to bond with their mother. Leaving babies to cry when they are calling for their mother can form distrust toward the mother and cause anxiety and inability to handle stress in later adulthood. Also they may still be to young to understand what you're doing so it might not work very well right now, when their older (2-5) that would be a good time to try this. I have never had personal experience with this but my sister in law did it with her kids and it was terrible to watch.

Answer (score 2):

When I analysed my situation, I understood it is just the stress and no sleep which made me come to this decision of putting babies in.a room and leaving them.
I realised how cruel it is. Babies need me and I shouldn't disappoint them .
I love them a lot and hope the situation turns better.

Comment: Note that if you feel overwhelmed, it is *better* to leave your kids in a safe place (like a crib/cot) and go somewhere and calm down, even if they cry. Don't beat yourself up if you need to do it form time to time.

Comment: Thanks Ida and I fully agree. And its not easy to have two twin babies and a. Step teenage daughter at home.